# incompatible types when initializing type 'int' using type

Tags: c

Here is minimal test case of what I am trying to do;

```
// minimal test case
#include <stdlib.h>

struct array {
    void *ptr;
    int numElements;
    int capacity;
};

struct task {
    char *task_name;
    int task_id;
};

#define NEW_ARRAY(TYPE, VARIABLE, CAPACITY) \
    struct array VARIABLE; \
    VARIABLE.ptr = malloc(CAPACITY * sizeof(TYPE)); \
    VARIABLE.capacity = CAPACITY; \
    VARIABLE.numElements = 0 \

#define array_for_each(TYPE, ELEM, ARRAY) \
    for (int i=0, ELEM = *((TYPE *)ARRAY.ptr); \
        i<ARRAY.numElements; \
        i++, ELEM = *((TYPE *)ARRAY.ptr + i) \
    ) \

int main() {
    NEW_ARRAY(struct task, my_tasks, 2);
    struct task tmp;

    array_for_each(struct task, tmp, my_tasks) {
        ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting;

> test.c:22:23: hata: incompatible types when initializing type 'int'
>   using type 'struct task'   for (int i=0, ELEM = *((TYPE *)ARRAY.ptr);
>   \

that macro line when expanded, turnes into this:

```
for (int i=0, tmp = *((struct task *)my_tasks.ptr); i<my_tasks.numElements; i++, tmp = *((struct task *)my_tasks.ptr + i) ) {
  ;
 }
```

Ok, so tmp is a `struct task` and I am casting my_tasks.ptr which is a `void *` to `struct task *` and dereferencing it, so that should give me a `struct task`. So I don't know why gcc is throwing me that error.

Comment: Because you're then assigning that `struct task` to a variable of type `int`?

Answer (score 2):

When you have code like:

```
for (int i=0, tmp = *((struct task *)my_tasks.ptr); ...
```

`tmp` is a new variable in the scope of the `for` loop and it's type is `int`.

Answer (score 1):

In a declaration like:

```
int i = 0, tmp = ....;
```

it is declaring `int`s called `i` and `tmp`.  But you try to initialize this new int `tmp` with a `struct task`.

I guess you were trying to combine the declaration `int i = 0;` with the statement `tmp = ....` referring to the existing variable `tmp`, however that is not possible. To fix this you could hoist the `ELEM=` part out to before the `for(`.

BTW consider making the loop work with a pointer instead of copying each element by value, then you can modify the values in the array. A bonus of that approach is that you don't even need `i`. (You can use pointer subtraction to know when you hit the end of the loop) so you would not run into the original problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop has two different valid syntaxes.  It can either be:

```
for (expr_opt1 ; expr_opt2 ; expr_opt3)
```

or

```
for (declartion expr_opt1 ; expr_opt2)
```

You are trying to mix the two by declaring a new variable, i, in the loop scope AND trying to initialize tmp.  The compiler thinks you are trying to declare *TWO* new variables, i and tmp, both of type int, with loop scope and then initializing tmp with a struct task.  The latter point is why is has an error.